# New user can't logon from her client computer

Tags: login, active-directory

I am a helpdesk person (still in school for networking). I have added a new user to AD (server 2003). The new user can't login from her desktop (it's a shared desktop) but other users can login there. The new user can login from any other computer, however, just not the one from which she should be working. Any ideas?

The client is using XP, and she waited about an hour before she tried to login.

Comment: What client OS?  Is there more than one Domain Controller?

Comment: Does she have the domain selected? Does the computer have internet access/network access? How long did they wait before trying to login once the account was created?

Comment: Start by looking at whats different with this PC... Check DNS servers. Make sure the computer is actually set to login to the domain and not the local machine. Make sure it's not in a DMZ or other segregated network VLAN. We need way more info if you want anyone here to help you.

Comment: The domain is selected at the login screen and yes the computer has internet/network access. everything seems to be fine unless she in particular tries to login

Comment: There are 5 domain controllers

Comment: Did the new user replicate to the other controllers?

Comment: Is the account in at least one of the local groups (Administrators, Power Users, Users, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

First thought is that the system is trying a domain controller that has not replicated the account.  With five DCs, that is possible.  What is the replication schedule?

Comment: With just a few exceptions, nothing in AD gets synched immediately.  If you need it *ASAP*, force a sync with 'repadmin /syncall' from a DC.